# Find out the caller of WM_SIZING

Tags: vb6, window-messages

I have a really huge project with hundreds of thousands lines of code. 
My application has a complex graphical interface.

For some reason, sometimes my main form is resized, and I just don't see why / how this happens.

To track down the reason for the resizing, I installed a window subclass.

```
Private Sub iSubclass_WndProc(ByVal bBefore As Boolean, bHandled As Boolean, lReturn As Long, ByVal lng_hWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As eMsg, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long, lParamUser As Long)
```

These are the parameters of the window message for WM_SIZING when this undesired resize occurs:

```
wParam = 9
lParam = 1697980  
lParamUser = 0
```

The resizing only occurs only like once each 2 hours, so debugging is really difficult already.

How could I track any further who / which function is responsible for the resizing?

Comment: sadly, the WM_SIZING doesn't contains anything useful to find out the sender. BTW, just only guessing, did you read this? [Windows 7 moves/resizes windows on monitor power cycle](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/windows-7-movesresizes-windows-on-monitor-power/1653aafb-848b-464a-8c69-1a68fbd106aa)

Comment: You may want to refocus the question - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem